# Signal routing with repeating goto tags

Tags: matlab, simulink, goto

I'm working on a model of a water distribution network. It contains various parts which are contained several times. To add a new part I currently copy the part from its individual .slx model to the network .slx . However then I need to rename all the from and goto tags of said part to avoid an error. How can i use the visibility tag to prevent the need for this, or even better make the routing local or get rid of this signal routing concept all together. For clarity of the model I would like to place the in and out ports on both sides of the block.

So any more elegant solutions on how to add a model would be greatly appreciated. In the enclosed image example, if I were to add another pipe (eg. ezPipe2)  I would have to rename all the tags in the new pipe model (8 in total, those in this layer and those in the subsystem they go to) which is impractical considering the size this network should eventually have. [image: Pipe Junction Pipe]

The goto tags go to a subsystem which contains the bits where the calculation is done. The example is for the pipe, one layer down. There is one more layer with the actual function.
[image: Pipe Subsytem]

Comment: I've embedded the images for you, they should show up momentarily (my edits still require peer review, so they might not be visible to you just yet)

Comment: Thanks, that makes it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be not to use goto and from blocks bur rather buses, to make your subsystems more portable, especially if you are using global goto/from blocks. You can use [Bus  Creator](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/buscreator.html) blocks to create the buses, and [Bus Selector](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/busselector.html) blocks to select the signals of interest. See [Create and Access a Bus](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/ug/creating-and-accessing-a-bus.html) in the documentation for more details. It requires more work upfront, but pays off in the long term, eespecially if re-using the same subsystem several times (in which case you may want to put it in a library).